# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null , Parameter name: queryString

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

The Following query is used for Gets list of customers(id and name, address) with sites(id and name) and buildings(id and name) of each customer.
The code looks like this:

```
var customers = this._databaseContext.Customers.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(p => p.customerActive.HasValue && p.customerActive.Value)
    .Include(p => p.Sites.Select(q => q.Buildings))
    .Select(c => new CustomerWithAddressDao
    {
        Id = c.customerID,
        Name = c.customerName,
        Address = new AddressDao
        {
            Street = c.Address1.street,
            Street2 = c.Address1.street2,
            City = c.Address1.city,
            StateId = c.Address1.stateID,
            Zip = c.Address1.zip,
            Zip4 = c.Address1.zip4,
            CountryId = c.Address1.countryID,
            Latitude = c.Address1.Latitude,
            Longitude = c.Address1.Longitude,
            County = c.Address1.County

        },
        Sites = c.Sites.Where(s => s.IsActive.HasValue && s.IsActive.Value)
        .Select(q => new SiteSlimDao
        {
            Id = q.Id,
            Name = q.Name,
            CustomerId = c.customerID,
            CustomFields = q.SiteCustomFields.Select(a => a.Value),
            Buildings = q.Buildings.Where(b => b.buildingActive.HasValue && b.buildingActive.Value)
            .Select(m => new BuildingSlimDao
            {
                Id = m.buildingID,
                Name = m.buildingName,
                SiteId = q.Id,
                CustomFields = m.BuildingCustomFields.Select(a => a.Value),
                BuildingTypeId = m.buildingTypeID
            }).OrderBy(b => b.Name).ToList()
        }).OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList()
    })
    .OrderBy(customer => customer.Name)
    .ToList();
```

The following error is showing up:

> ```
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: queryString
>    at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateQuery[T](String queryString, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.CreateObjectQuery(Boolean asNoTracking, Nullable`1 streaming, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy)
>    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.AsNoTracking()
>    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.AsNoTracking()
> ```

I have also disabled the lazy loading since we are using the extension method.
Below are the classes defined which are used in the linq query

```
public class CustomerWithAddressDao
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<SiteSlimDao> Sites { get; set; }
        public AddressDao Address { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public partial class AddressDao
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int? StateId { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public int? Zip4 { get; set; }
        public int? CountryId { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public decimal? Latitude { get; set; }
        public decimal? Longitude { get; set; }
        public string TimeZoneName { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public class SiteSlimDao
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> CustomFields { get; set; }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int LicenceCount { get; set; }
        public IList<BuildingSlimDao> Buildings { get; set; }
        public string AddressStr { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class BuildingSlimDao
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? BuildingTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }        
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> CustomFields { get; set; }
        public string AddressStr { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What version of entity framework are you using?

Comment: @RandyRietdijk EF 6.0.0

Comment: Does it make a difference if you temporarily comment the `m.BuildingCustomFields` in the last select statement?

Comment: @RandyRietdijk No actually.

Comment: I see another dependency, `q.SiteCustomFields`, could you comment that one aswell together with the `m.BuildingCustomFields` and try again? I have a feeling the error is caused by classes that are not included in the query by EF.

Comment: @RandyRietdijk Let me try it and let u known .

Comment: @RandyRietdijk Even After commenting out it is still giving error to some specific cases in staging.

Comment: There is many things to check, use a native query to check which field is null

Comment: @qazwsx123 :majorly all the field are in the string format which can be nullable also so we really need to check the native query ?? .

Comment: @VIkas you can capture the generated query from EF and then check which field is null OR you can separate the massive select function and execute your LINQ query and then after all the data fetched from the database then you can easily find the problem.